# Filter datatable in JSF : null pointer exception - parameters issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am implementing a primefaces datatable with a filter for each column.

The data displayed in the table are resulting from a query that uses some parameters passed by the user through a selectcheckboxMenu.

I can display the data but when I try to apply a filter I got a null pointer exception.

Here is the datatable code :

```
      <p:dataTable id ="rows"  rows="15"   value="#{poc_InputManager.stockFiltered}" var="s" tableStyle="width:auto"  >                           
             <p:column filterBy="#{s.locationcode}" headerText="LocationCode"> 
             <h:outputText value="#{s.locationcode}"/>
             </p:column>                                  
             <p:column filterBy="#{s.itemcode}" headerText="itemCode"> 
             <h:outputText value="#{s.itemcode}"/>
             </p:column>               
             <p:column filterBy="#{s.stock}" headerText="Stock"> 
             <h:outputText value="#{s.stock}"/>
             </p:column>                                             
        </p:dataTable>
```

And here is the query code :

```
         Query query = session.createQuery("FROM POC_HealthyStock WHERE locationcode IN (:ids) AND itemcode=:itc");
         query.setParameterList("ids",fil);
         query.setParameter("itc",item);
```

The parameters are passed this way :

```
    <p:commandButton  style="margin-left:10px;" value="Submit"  ajax="false" action="#{navigator.filterData}">

        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{navigator.selectedsta}" value="#{checkboxMenu.selectedSTAs}" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{navigator.allsta}" value="#{checkboxMenu.stas}" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{poc_InputManager.selectedsta}" value="#{checkboxMenu.selectedSTAs}" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{poc_InputManager.selecteditem}" value="#{checkboxMenu.selectedItem}" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

The error trace is :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Collection must be not null!
at    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameterList(AbstractQueryImpl.java:871)
at dao.POC_HealthyStockDAO.getAllStocksFiltered(POC_HealthyStockDAO.java:27)
at bean.poc_InputManager.getStockFiltered(poc_InputManager.java:55)
```

I understand that the error is caused by the fact that the query can't access the parameters when I try to filter the datatable.

So I wonder how I should proceed to pass the parameters to the query. 
I have looked after the filterEvent but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Is it @ViewScoped ? I'm not sure it's the reason for your issue but it might be. I never used filters on datatable so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Create an mcve…  totally unclear how?all works and where the 'fil' collection comes from

Comment: Remove the Hibernate dependency from the question. It is not responsible doing this thing. Instead show how you initialize the collection (`fil`) in the corresponding backing bean. It appears that you need the `filteredValue="#{bean.fil}"` attribute corresponding to a property of an appropriate collection type in the backing bean.

Comment: Better to use a LazyDataModel… way more control over things

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The problem was effectively a viewscoped on a bean.